# How to add search Button in android actionbar

Tags: android, xml

I want to add search button in android action bar . I have added a menu item in my XML menu resource.

```
<item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

The configuration file has been saved in the res/xml/ project directory (and is traditionally named searchable.xml).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/app_name" >
</searchable>
```

Then what have I to do to show the search button in Android ? I have following this article .

http://codetheory.in/adding-search-to-android/

Any suggesstion will be of great help .